# jtextfiled not retrieving the value picked from combobox

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I want retrieve the value picked from combo box to jtextfield. As per my UI combobox is in 4th. So I coded:

```
pst.setString(4, (String)cmbPaySub.getSelectedItem());
```

and the error pop-up:

> Parameter index out of range.(4> number of parameters, which is 1".

I tried by coding;

```
pst.setString(1, (String)cmbPaySub.getSelectedItem());
```

Neither error will pop-up and value also not picking up.

```
private void cmbPaySubActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sipnena", "root", "");
        String sql="select * from payments where cmbSubject=?";
        PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(4, (String)cmbPaySub.getSelectedItem());

        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            txtFee.setText(rs.getString("Fee"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Kindly help me to retrieve the value to the jtextfield.

Comment: `pst.setString(4` its `pst.setString(1` index position will start from `1`.

Comment: Hi I coded as 1 also. But nothing happended

Comment: Means are getting same error?

Comment: You want to receive data from cmbPaySub to txtFee? If its right, that's not your code mean to do

Comment: SatyaTNV  not a error. Also not picking up the value.

Comment: Guspan Tanadi Can you reccomend me that what are the alterations I should do with my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the result you're replacing the entire text by the result's value in a loop so only the last value will show:

```
while(rs.next()){
    txtFee.setText(rs.getString("Fee"));
}
```

You should concatenate all the values, and then set the text:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while(rs.next()){
    text.append(rs.getString("Fee"));
    text.append("\n");
}
txtFee.setText(text.toString());
```